# c++ overloaded << prints adress of object attribute, instead of actual value

Tags: c++, class, overloading, ostream

So I am learning operation overloading.
I am trying to overload << to print object properties.
In my case Properties is a class that inherits the public section of the person class.
This is what i have:

```
    class Person {
    private:
        string name;
        int egn;
        string adress;
    public:
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Person& c);
    }

    ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Person& c)          
    {
        out << "Person name: " << c.name << "\n" << "Person egn: " << c.egn;
        return out;
    }
    int main()
    {  
        Properties* person_obj_1 = new Properties();
        person_obj_1 = add_person(person_obj_1);//Add some values 
        cout << person_obj_1 << "\n";
    }
```

And the output I get is 000001CE89252130. This is not what I want. I need to print the actual values of my attributes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `person_obj_1` is a `Properties` pointer, not a `Person` object/reference

Comment: `person_obj_1` is a pointer, i.e. it holds an address, and this is what you get when you `cout` it.  `*person_obj_1` would be the actual object, but it is of type `Properties`, not `Person`, so I don't see an `operator<<` overload for it.

Comment: Also you allocate a `new Properties()` and assign to `person_obj_1`. But then you immediatly re-assign it, so the previously allocated object is leaked.

Comment: `Properties person_obj_1;` is what you want. `add_person` should be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: you get the same effect with the built in `<<`. Try to print the integer pointer at by `int* x = new int(42);`

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're printing a `Properties*` instead of a `Person` object. That is, to get your expected result you need to use `cout` on a `Person` object for which you've overloaded `operator<<` instead of `Properties*` which is a pointer.